# Login failed for user 'user' VB.NET app and SQL connection

Tags: vb.net, authentication

[please see SQL Management Screen Shot Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3rRh.png)

I am getting:

> system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception: ' login failed for user 'public_user'.'

when I run my application on VB.NET. Please see the link to check settings on my SQL management studio. This application was running flawlessly previously, however I swapped my HDD to SSD and reinstalled SQL and Visual Studio. Since then I am failing to login as `public_user`.

I ran a query on SQL as `public_user` and I am not getting any error message. When I run the application, it does connect to SQL on the app, but it fails to load `table1` on `datagridview`.

I've put `tableadapter` at the beginning on the mainform, at the end, under `sqlconnection1.open`, basically any possible places, however I am still getting the same error.

The source code is below, please help me to find the solution:

- VB.NET
- Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2
- Windows 10 OS

  ```
  Timer1.Enabled = True
  Dim sqlconnection1 As New SqlConnection("server = xxx-xxx-xxx;user id=public_user; password=xxxxxx; Trusted_Connection=True; connection timeout=5")
  Dim cmdsql As New SqlCommand

  cmdsql.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [LM2].[dbo].[Table_1]"
  cmdsql.CommandType = CommandType.Text

  cmdsql.Connection = sqlconnection1
  Me.Table_1TableAdapter.Fill(Me.LM2DataSet2.Table_1)




  Try
      sqlconnection1.Open()
      If ConnectionState.Open Then
          MsgBox("Connected To SQL")

      Else
          MsgBox("Failed To Connect SQL")
      End If
  Catch ex As DataException
      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
  End Try
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've found the solution. When i copied SLN from the old HDD and transferred to SSD, for some reason it automatically deleted the ID and password on ConnectionString settings. I've entered those details on main settings and it is working fine. I had in total 5 SQL Databases which was connecting to my App, and all of them were using same login details for public_user. when i enter credentials it worked for all SQL databases.